# How to stop Preview's pen from turning into a hand?

Tags: preview, drawing

I want to draw a couple lines when annotating a PDF with Preview.

But, when I get close to the first line, the tool automatically switches from a pen to a hand.

For example, if I try to hand-draw the symbol `∀`:

1. Draw a `V`
2. Try to draw the `-` part
3. NOPE - Preview switches from "pen" tool to "hand"/grabber tool, and *moves* the V instead

Is there a way to turn off the hand tool so I can draw normally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's turning into a hand because it's letting you drag the existing line, as you may have inferred. Preview doesn't have a way of ignoring the existing line and just drawing a new line.

To workaround this, you could draw the center line somewhere else, then drag it into place.

Comment: Dang, that's too bad. Thanks for confirming anyway!